# How to see a single html page on centOs server

Tags: centos, centos7

I run a local server and I installed centOS on it and I can access on this server with ssh command line. I set my dns name and etc.

on my server I create a user called: 'masoud'.

then I created a `index.html` file. now I want to see this `index.html` with my ip address. on other hand how can I see this `index.html` file on my browser?

I tested there url's on my browser but I cannot see anything.

```
92.168.15.9/index.html
92.168.15.9
92.168.15.9:80/index.html
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Apache (or similar webserver) is installed?
- Apache (or installed webserver) is running?
- index.html is in the doc root (check apache configs)
- index.html has the correct permissions/owner (see error/access logs)
- Check the Apache error/access logs?
- If there are firewalls, are they setup to allow http traffic to/from the server?